# Modifying the object behind ListView, when clicking a button

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have this rather simple app, where it will populate the spesific Module with objects, called: Question. This object has public attributes, such as: String question {get; set;}, and int selectedAnswer{get; set;}.

What I would like to achieve, is that when the user presses eather YesButton or NoButton -button, that would change the selectedAnswer inside that specific object to 0-2. In this case, if the user pressses No, that value inside this object changes to 1, if Yes, it will turn into 2. Default is 0.

How can I refer to that object, at the Clicked-eventhandler? Here's the XML page:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}"
                  x:Name="QuestionsList_module"

                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      Margin="10,10" >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="10, 20, 0, 10" >

                            <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>

                            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding questionList}"
                                      x:Name="Item"
                                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                                      Margin="30,30">

                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ViewCell>

                                            <StackLayout Padding="0,10,0,10">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding question}"></Label>

                                                <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0,20,0,10">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >

                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                    <Button Margin="0,0,20,0" x:Name="YesButton" Text="YES" FontAttributes="Bold" BorderColor="LightGreen"  BorderWidth="5" CornerRadius="20" Clicked="YesButton_Clicked" />

                                                    <Button Margin="0,0,20,0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NoButton" Text="NO" FontAttributes="Bold" BorderColor="HotPink"  BorderWidth="5" CornerRadius="20" />

                                                </Grid>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </ViewCell>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

And here's my so far attempt to get the information inside the sender:

```
private void YesButton_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var button = (Button)sender;

            Grid listview = (Grid)button.Parent;
            StackLayout ss = (StackLayout)listview.Parent;


        }
```

And like this, I'm able to get the upper label, but still not gaining "access" to the object itself.

Please note, that all Modules are type: ObservableCollection and all Question-objects are also in ObservableCollection and the final Model will look like this:

```
new Module{
name = "this is the name of this module",
description = "Here goes the description",
isVisible = false,
ModuleIsChecked = false,
questionList = "And here's the list of those questions in ObservableCollection -list"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `BindingContext` of the button to get the bound object, then cast it to the correct type

```
var button = (Button)sender;

// cast to the appropriate class
var item = (Question)button.BindingContext;
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick! Boy, do I feel stupid now, but clearly I don't understant the Binding in Xamarin well enough yet. Back to studying!